# Run GPupdate in a hidden style

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I created a `.bat` file calls a `PowerShell` script but a command prompt window continues to appear(it flashes). How can I do to make the command prompt hidden.
the powershell script `update.ps1` contains `GPupdate /force`
Below is my code:

`@echo off
PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -File "update.ps1" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -noProfile -NonInteractive`

Comment: Use a Vbscript to run `gpupdate` instead.

Comment: How can i do it

Answer (score 0):

Create a scheduled tasks with another user (system for example)
the task will run in background